# how can i print a boolean value in JSON in table

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I want to print a boolean value from JSON into a table, if I access directly to the status field, an empty value is displayed
here is an example of json file:

```
    {
                'name':'client'
                'status':true,
                'method':'masterCard',
                'amount':'1700',

                }
```

jsx file :

```
    const columns = [
     {
            title: "name",
            dataIndex: "name",
            key: "name",
            width: "20%"
          },
           {
            title: "status",
            dataIndex: "status",
            key: "status",
            width: "20%"
          },
          {title: "Method Paiment",
            dataIndex: "method",
            key: "method",
            width: "20%",

          }]
```

Comment: what is your expection ouput

Comment: nothing displayed

Comment: do you want convert from second JSON to first JSON?

Comment: Please learn [the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access and process nested objects and arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-and-arrays)

Comment: I'm going to guess you could give in a template for your columns. Could you add which library you are using for displaying your table? You mention something about jsontable?

Comment: @HienNguyen He doesn't want to convert as far as I see, he just shows one row in the first one, and in the second the columns on how they will look?

Comment: I'm sorry for that , but i just identify my error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution i found is to do a condition (is true or false ):

```
const columns = [
 {
        title: "name",
        dataIndex: "name",
        key: "name",
        width: "20%"
      },
       {
        title: "status",
        dataIndex: "status",
        key: "status",
        width: "20%",
        render: statut => {
          if (statut == true) {
            return (
              <Tag color="#1890ff" key={statut}>
                Is True
              </Tag>
            );
          }

            return (
              <Tag color="#d48806" key={statut}>
                Is False
              </Tag>
            );


        }
      },
      {title: "Method Paiment",
        dataIndex: "method",
        key: "method",
        width: "20%",

      }]
```